# Does Kendo UI for web support c# MVC 4?

Tags: kendo-ui

Does Kendo-UI for web support MVC 4 ?

I am trying to implemented Grid in Kendo with custom filter menu with radio button. It seems that is not being supported as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Kendo supports Asp.Net MVC 4 , all of their docs for Razor MVC will work in MVC 4.  I currently use a gird in many different instances in MVC 4

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ive done lots of project with Kendo ui and mvc 4

Answer (score 0):

From kendo ui blog

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-11-29/the_facts_on_using_kendo_ui_with_asp_net_webapi.aspx

"The answer is of course a resounding "YES!".

Answer (score 0):

I think, that user2018741 is talking about MVC Server Wrappers. And they are not in Kendo UI WEB edition.